# Adding a second loss mask in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, loss

I'm using google's seq2seq [library](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/) and based on some computations that I do between the predictions and the input I would like to zero out some of the losses for certain time steps (not for padding).

What I do is basically to go through each batch then through each time step of the decoder (logits) and for eatc time step I add "a zero or a one" to a list (based on my computation). This list should then be converted to a tensor and multiplied by the losses.

My problem is the shape of the tensor reurned by the sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is variable, its not always the shape of the target tensor. So there is a mismatch of dimensions.  Has anyone does something like this before and can share it, or know why this happens.

Comment: I don't often use sparse matrices, this seems like a place to use dense matrices, e.g.: `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. No?

Comment: Shouldn't the logits and targets have the same shape for softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?  In seq2seq, the have different shapes.

Comment: Why is it not the same size? Can you clarify what you're doing there?

Comment: I don't understand your question. sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits returns the same shape as the target tensor